# Print command in matrices to generate inactive numbers

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I would like to generate a matrix with elements that come from a print command and are numbers and then multiply the first matrix by another one, element by element.

However, I would like the numbers to remain inactive, and this is the point of my confusion. That is when, i.e, I have in an element $2 \cdot2$ I want it to be like that rather than give me back $4$.

If the above is not clear I will illustrate with a minimal example. I would like the following

$\begin{matrix}
\langle 2 2 \rangle \langle 2 2 \rangle & \langle 2 3 \rangle \langle 2 3 \rangle & \langle 2 4 \rangle \langle 2 4 \rangle\\
\langle 3 2 \rangle \langle 3 2 \rangle & \langle 3 3 \rangle \langle 3 3 \rangle & \langle 3 4 \rangle \langle 3 4 \rangle\\
\langle 4 2 \rangle \langle 4 2 \rangle & \langle 4 3 \rangle \langle 4 3 \rangle & \langle 4 4 \rangle \langle 4 4 \rangle\\
\end{matrix}$

The code that I tried

```
Op1p2[p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_] := 
 Print[MatrixForm[
   Table[\[LeftAngleBracket]p1, p2\[RightAngleBracket], {p1, 2, 
      4}, {p2, 2, 4}] Table[\[LeftAngleBracket]p3, 
      p4\[RightAngleBracket], {p3, 2, 4}, {p4, 2, 4}]]]
```

but when I run the command `Op1p2[p1, p2, p3, p4]` it gives back

[image: wrong result]

which is not the desired form.

I tried some alternatives to the above code by using `Inactive` but it has not worked so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is just for display, you could override the formatting of [`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power) so that squares render as desired:

```
MakeBoxes[unsquaredForm[e_], form_]:=Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    Unprotect[Power];
    MakeBoxes[Power[a_, 2], form]:=MakeBoxes[a a, form],

    MakeBoxes[e, form],

    MakeBoxes[Power[a_,2], form]=.;
    Protect[Power]
]
```

Then:

```
unsquaredForm @ MatrixForm[
    Table[\[LeftAngleBracket]p1,p2\[RightAngleBracket],{p1,2,4},{p2,2,4}]^2
] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \langle 2,2\rangle  \langle 2,2\rangle  & \langle 2,3\rangle  \langle 2,3\rangle  &
>    \langle 2,4\rangle  \langle 2,4\rangle  \\
>  \langle 3,2\rangle  \langle 3,2\rangle  & \langle 3,3\rangle  \langle 3,3\rangle  &
>    \langle 3,4\rangle  \langle 3,4\rangle  \\
>  \langle 4,2\rangle  \langle 4,2\rangle  & \langle 4,3\rangle  \langle 4,3\rangle  &
>    \langle 4,4\rangle  \langle 4,4\rangle  \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: yes this code is only for display. I just want to see big matrices in that form so that I know how to set up some interesting questions. Great answer and resolution btw. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Another way

```
Outer[HoldForm[〈##〉 〈##〉] &, #, #] &@Range[2, 4] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \langle 2,2\rangle  \langle 2,2\rangle  & \langle 2,3\rangle  \langle 2,3\rangle  & \langle 2,4\rangle  \langle 2,4\rangle  \\
>  \langle 3,2\rangle  \langle 3,2\rangle  & \langle 3,3\rangle  \langle 3,3\rangle  & \langle 3,4\rangle  \langle 3,4\rangle  \\
>  \langle 4,2\rangle  \langle 4,2\rangle  & \langle 4,3\rangle  \langle 4,3\rangle  & \langle 4,4\rangle  \langle 4,4\rangle  \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$